# HTML Not showing properly unless formatted

Tags: html

I have a program that generates the following code:

```
    <div style='width:10%'><hr></div><div style='width:10%'><span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First1 Last1</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span><span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First2 Last2</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span><span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First3 Last3</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span><span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First4 Last4</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span><span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First5 Last5</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span><span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First6 Last6</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span><span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First7 Last7</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span><span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First8 Last8</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span></div>
```

If I put that into  it does not show up properly.

If I manually format the code, it then shows up properly. Why is that.

```
     <div style='width:10%'><hr></div>
     <div style='width:10%'>
       <span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First1 Last1</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span>
       <span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First2 Last2</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span>
       <span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First3 Last3</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span>
       <span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First4 Last4</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span>
       <span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First5 Last5</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span>
       <span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First6 Last6</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span>
       <span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First7 Last7</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span>
       <span style='white-space: nowrap;'>First8 Last8</span><span style=' margin-left:20px;'></span>
     </div>
```

Comment: Works [here JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bsxkpwLr/), must be other causes in some other code

Comment: @Billy I believe what he means is that formatted, it arranges in rows, but unformatted, it arranges them in columns.

Comment: What are you using to generate the code? maybe you need to include a carriage return and/or line feed in the string being populated.

Comment: @Billy If you then paste the formatted code, you will see that it displays differently than what you have on JSFiddle.

Comment: I used the top code and it comes out alright, does he mean he wants it formatted like the bottom code, indented, when it comes out of the generator ?

Comment: @Josh, no difference for me [jsFiddle with the top code](http://jsfiddle.net/bsxkpwLr/) and [jsFiddle with bottom code](http://jsfiddle.net/bsxkpwLr/1/)

Comment: @Billy Your original JSFiddle outputs everything on one line? I guess we're seeing different things.

Comment: strange, it doesn't for me ? Anyone else getting it on the same line ?

Comment: @Billy maybe you have a very large resolution/are zoomed out.

Comment: Neither, Never mind, question answered now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same reason why these are different:

(different lines:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<div style='width:1%'>
<span style='white-space:nowrap;'>TTTTTTTT</span>
<span style='white-space:nowrap;'>A</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and (same line:)

```
<html>
<body>
<div style='width:1%'>
<span style='white-space:nowrap;'>TTTTTTTT</span><span style='white-space:nowrap;'>A</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first span is using more than the allocated width, but it won't wrap the text(caused by nowrap) so you see it all on one line, but then the next span will start on the next line.